# How can I add new line to the file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, file-management

I am using windows programming my project requires working with files I tried the following code

```
HANDLE hFile; 
char DataBuffer[255] = "This is some test data to write to the file.";
DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
DataBuffer[dwBytesToWrite+1]='\n';
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;



hFile = CreateFile(L"Myfile.txt",                // name of the write
                   GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                   0,                      // do not share
                   NULL,                   // default security
                   CREATE_ALWAYS,             // create new file only
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                   NULL);
```

The below code was used add two lines to the file

```
     bErrorFlag = WriteFile( 
                hFile,           // open file handle
                DataBuffer,      // start of data to write
                dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
                &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                NULL);            // no overlapped structure
char DataBuffer1[] = "\n\nThe second line of code\n\n";
dwBytesToWrite=sizeof(DataBuffer1);

 bErrorFlag = WriteFile( 
                hFile,           // open file handle
                DataBuffer1,      // start of data to write
                dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
                &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                NULL);
```

The program works fine but when i try to open "Myfile.txt" with the notepad i get the following results

" This is some test data to write to the file.The second line of code. "

Is there any other way to insert a new line to a file?

Comment: `DataBuffer[dwBytesToWrite+1]='\n';` don't add +1, because `length` will always be +1 than last index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\r\n` instead of `\n` for `newline`.

Comment: Isn't the C library translating automatically `\n` to the eol sequence?

Comment: Self-answer to my comment: `WriteFile` is not from the C library.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
char DataBuffer1[] = "\n\nThe second line of code\n\n";
```

Use

```
char DataBuffer1[] = "\r\nThe second line of code\r\n";
```